# wget a whole website, no sound

Tags: wget

My friends showed me a [site](http://www.flappyplane.net) and I want to download this site for offline use, in basic .html format

Using the command:

```
wget -r -k -p "www.flappyplane.net"
```

I was able to obtain the site for offline use but it has no sound... any help on getting it? note: I do not want any 3rd party software such as chrome extensions as much as possible, I want to be able to use wget to obatain this.

if there really is no other way with wget then please share with me this method.

Comment: Download all the JavaScript files referenced in the HTML and then read through them to find out where the sound files are kept, and then try and grab them.

Comment: if site generating links to sound files dynamically, you cant get it with wget ;(